# Oracle-Apex Switch Item value

Tags: oracle-apex

I have column which is data type number(1,0), I decide to use switch item for this column.
I set custom settings. 1 for On and 0 for off.

When I try to edit column, and use off(0) I get error - Column_name must match the values 1 and 0. 
When I use On value all works fine.

Comment: Are you getting the error from an APEX validation, or from the Oracle database?

Comment: I get error from apex, I can't see anything in log table

Comment: What is the exact error message? Sounds like there's something wrong with the validation on the switch item. A database error or more serious APEX error would be in the log.

Comment: Exact error - Column_name must match the values 1 and 0.

Comment: I don't use validation, only insert process

Comment: If there's no "ORA-" error number and no application error in the log, then it is almost certainly being generated by a check or validation in the object properties. Look there.

Comment: This is from view debug > errors - #LABEL# must match the values 1 and 0.

Comment: I add screenshot

Comment: That is a validation error.

Answer (score 2):

Goku, in apex, the best way to learn (you said yourself you're a beginner) is to write a lot of small apps in a dev environment that only perform one thing. That way you can isolate issues and study behavior in detail. I suggest you do the same for this switch item issue to figure out what the problem is. You have not provided enough information for anyone to answer it so users are giving you their best guesses.
So this is what I did. Create test table

```
create table so_test_with_switch (
    so_test_with_switch_id         number generated by default on null as identity  
                                   constraint so_test_with_switc_id_pk primary key,
    name                           varchar2(255),
    switchval                      number
);
```

Create a report and form in apex, change the form item for switchval page item (P32_SWITCHVAL) to "Switch" with custom settings: 1 for On and 0 for off. I tested and my form worked fine. The error message indicates that the value apex is getting does not match either 1 or 0 so it must get that value from somewhere else. In my case I added an after submit computation to set the value of P32_SWITCHVAL to 'Y'. Saved my changes, ran the form, clicked "Apply Changes" and I got the same error as you. 
It is up to you to figure out where your page item is getting the other value from. Go through your page, investigate and debug. The key to finding the solution is in your code.
--Koen

Comment: From Oracle known issues "If you have a Switch item defined using custom component settings with the "Off Value" set to "0", then the zero value will not be returned correctly."

Comment: I use 19.2 without the necessary patch

Comment: Easiest workaround is to use a select list until you have applied the patch.